# Copy the values from a column in one table to a column in another table where another value matches MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am kind of stuck trying to write a MySQL query...I wrote a query earlier but that did not work. What I am trying to do is that we have 2 tables in our MySQL.

```
table name: customers
column name: customers_default_address_id

table name: address_book
column name: address_book_id
```

I want to populate `customers_default_address_id` with `address_book_id` where `customer_id` is the common value in both tables

But there are multiple `address_book_id` where `customer_id` is same so the query should assign only one of the `address_book_id` entries.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: please post the query you attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update table1 set customers_default_address_id=(
    select address_book_id from table2 where
        table1.customer_id=table2.customer_id limit 1
)
```

or you can use max() in the internal query instead of limit 1